# Function signature not found despite showing with methods(...)

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia, so this might be trivial.

I have a function definition within a module that looks like (using URIParser):

```
function add!(graph::Graph,
              subject::URI,
              predicate::URI,
              object::URI)
    ...
end
```

Outside of the module, I call:

```
add!(g, URIParser.URI("http://test.org/1"), URIParser.URI("http://test.org/2"), URIParser.URI("http://test.org/1"))
```

Which gives me this error:

```
ERROR: no method add!(Graph,URI,URI,URI)
 in include at boot.jl:238
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
at /Users/jbaran/src/RDF/src/RDF.jl:79
```

Weird. Because when I can see a matching signature:

```
julia> methods(RDF.add!)
# 4 methods for generic function "add!":
add!(graph::Graph,subject::URI,predicate::URI,object::Number) at /Users/jbaran/src/RDF/src/RDF.jl:29
add!(graph::Graph,subject::URI,predicate::URI,object::String) at /Users/jbaran/src/RDF/src/RDF.jl:36
add!(graph::Graph,subject::URI,predicate::URI,object::URI) at /Users/jbaran/src/RDF/src/RDF.jl:43
add!(graph::Graph,statement::Statement) at /Users/jbaran/src/RDF/src/RDF.jl:68
```

At first I thought it was my use of object::Union(...), but even when I define three functions with Number, String, and URI, I get this error.

Is there something obvious that I am missing? I am using Julia 0.2.1 x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0, by the way.

Thanks,

Kim

Comment: What's happens if you do `RDF.add!(g, URIParser.URI("http://test.org/1"), URIParser.URI("http://test.org/2"), URIParser.URI("http://test.org/1"))`?

Comment: Also works, but ultimately went for the implementation given in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you may be getting bit by the very slight difference between method **extension** and function **shadowing**.

Here's the short of it. When you write `function add!(::Graph, ...); …; end;`, Julia looks at *just* your local scope and sees if `add!` is defined.  If it is, then it will extend that function with this new method signature.  But if it's not already defined locally, then Julia creates a new local variable `add!` for that function.

As JMW's comment suggests, I bet that you have *two* independent `add!` functions. `Base.add!` and `RDF.add!`.  In your RDF module, you're shadowing the definition of `Base.add!`.  This is similar to how you can name a local variable `pi = 3` without affecting the real `Base.pi` in other scopes.  But in this case, you want to merge your methods with the `Base.add!` function and let multiple dispatch take care of the resolution.

There are two ways to get the method extension behavior:

1. Within your `module RDF` scope, say `import Base: add!`.  This explicitly brings `Base.add!` into your local scope as `add!`, allowing method extension.
2. Explicitly define your methods as `function Base.add!(graph::Graph, …)`.  I like this form as it more explicitly documents your intentions to extend the `Base` function at the definition site.

This could definitely be better documented. There's a short reference to this in the [Modules](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/modules/) section, and there's currently [a pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/7700/files?short_path=c3408de#diff-c3408de56388e517a8975797c90d9448) that should be merged soon that will help.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I went for your second suggestion, also read up on scope, and everything works fine now!