# Can I write I Julia method that works "whenever possible" like a c++ template function?

Tags: polymorphism, julia

`rand` works with ranges:

```
rand(1:10)
```

I'd like to make `rand` work with `Array`, and anything that is indexable and has `length`:

```
import Base.Random
rand(thing) = thing[rand(1:length(thing))]

array = {1, 2, 3}
myRand(array)

range = 1:8
myRand(range)

tupple = (1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c")
myRand(tupple)
```

… but if I try this, my implementation stack overflows, presumably because it is completely general and matches everything passed, so it ends up calling itself?

Is there a way to fix this? I want to better understand Julia's polymorphic functions rather than get a fix for this particular (probably silly) function specialisation.

Is there also a tool to discover the various implementations that are available, and debug which will be called with particular arguments?

---

Okay, some digging. This is interesting…

I'll start up a fresh REPL, and:

```
julia> import Base.Random

julia> rand(thing) = thing[rand(1:length(thing))]
rand (generic function with 1 method)

julia> rand({1,2,3})
ERROR: stack overflow
 in rand at none:1 (repeats 80000 times)
```

…Oh dear, that's the recursive call and stack overflow I was talking about.

But, watch this. I kill Julia and start the REPL again. This time I `import Base.Random.rand`:

```
julia> import Base.Random.rand

julia> rand(thing) = thing[rand(1:length(thing))]
rand (generic function with 33 methods)

julia> rand({1,2,3})
3
```

It works – it added my new implementation to all the others, and picked the right one.

So, the answer to my first question seems to be – "it just works". Which is amazing. How does that work?!

But there's a slightly less interesting sounding question about modules, and why `import Base.Random` doesn't pull in the `rand` method or give an error, but `import Base.Random.rand` does.

Comment: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method extension

As some have pointed, Julia let you *extend* functions: you can have functions that work differently for different types (see [this part of the documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/methods/)).

For example:

```
f(x) = 2
f(x::Int) = x
```

In this example, we have a version (or *method*) of the function that is called if (and only if) the argument is of the type `Int`. The first one is called otherwise.

We say that we have extended the `f` function, and now it has 2 methods.

### Your Problem

What you want, then, is to extend the `rand` function.

You want your `rand` function, if called with a argument that was not caught by other methods, to execute `thing[rand(1:length(thing))]`. If done correctly, you would call the `rand` method that is applied to a `Range` object, since you are passing `1:length(thing)` as argument.

Although flawed (what if `thing` doesn't have a length, e.g. a complex number?), I would say your first attempt was very reasonable.

**The problem**: `rand` couldn't be extended on the first version of your program. According to [this piece of documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/modules/#summary-of-module-usage), writing `import Base.Random` doesn't make `rand` available for method extension.

While trying to extend `rand`, you actually *overwrite* the `rand` function. After this, when you call the function `rand`, there is only your method!

Remember, you were relying on the fact that a method for ranges (e.g. `rand(1:10)`) was defined elsewere, and that it gave the result you expected. What happened was that this method was overwritten by yours, so your method is called again (recursively).

**The solution**: import `rand` such as it is available to extension. You can see that on the table on the documentation.

Notice that your second program (the one with `import Base.Random.rand`) and Colin's program (the one with `importall Base.Random`) did exactly that. That's why they work.

Keep in mind what methods are or are not available for extension, and if the documentation isn't clear enough, a bug report (or maybe a fix) will be welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's great. I read the doc you linked to and the table in there seems to suggest that `import Base.Random` should make all the methods in `Base.Random` available for extension. This does feel like a sharp corner for a new user, so I'll try and file a suggestion.

Comment: I think there is a confusion: you can extend `rand` after doing `import Base.Random`. But to do this, you have to do it like this:

    `Base.Random.rand(thing) = thing[Base.Random.rand(1:length(thing)]`.

Since what is available for extension (and brought into scope) is `Base.Random.rand` and not `rand` itself.

Comment: You can argue that, contrary to the documentation, `rand` is brought into scope. The thing is that it's brought into scope by default (you can use it before the import statement).

I suggest writing `using Module` whenever you want to import a module. This way, you can acess all exported methods without having to type `Module.method`.

Comment: Okay – I'm clearly quite confused :-) I'll go and read more, thank you. I do find it _slightly_ concerning I've got so confused, and not had a warning in the REPL that I'm probably being dumb… Julia feel well thought out and natural. Here I've been caught out finding there are significant hidden subtleties with something I'm aware of, in contrast to finding things I'm not aware of that I need to learn. If that makes sense?

Comment: The differences between the `using`, `import` and `importall` are pretty hard to figure out. Try to use the table I provided, and test with a module of yours (make a simple one just for testing purposes). I believe this will help.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to make this a comment, but it ended up being too long:

Note two other approaches that will also "just work":

```
Base.rand(thing) = thing[rand(1:length(thing))]
rand({1,2,3})
```

Or you could also use:

```
importall Base.Random
rand(thing) = thing[rand(1:length(thing))]
rand({1,2,3})
```

When you just use `import Base.Random` that won't actually allow you to extend `Base.rand` with your locally defined `rand`. This is because the `import` statement should only be used with functions, not modules. If you want to import all the functions in a module, you need to use `importall` (as in my example above). Alternatively (as I have done above), you can just directly reference the module in your function definition `Base.rand`.

Admittedly, last time I looked through the docs, this point could definitely have been made clearer. It may be addressed in the latest version though.

As to the rest of your question (why it "just works"?), I'm not convinced I can give a smart concise answer to this so I might leave it for someone else.

Also, [partial duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948941/function-signature-not-found-despite-showing-with-methods).

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for the answer – I've no idea why you were a given a down vote, as what you say agrees with the other answers, appears to be correct, and it helpful! Have a +1 form me, to get you back to 0. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Benjohn Yes, a strange down-vote. No worries :-) My concern was helping you, and if I did that, then I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

As another pointed out, explicitly specifying `Base.rand=` instead of `rand=` adds a method to the `rand` function definition in Base, instead of completely replacing it.

For example,

```
julia> Base.rand(x::Any)=x[rand(1:length(x)]
rand (generic function with 33 methods)
```

The reason this works has to do with Julia's [abstract type system](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#abstract-types). When Julia is looking for a function with a matching method signature, it starts at the leaf node of the defined types, (e.g. whether or not x is an Int8), and then moves up the type hierarchy until it finds a function with a matching signature. At the top of the type hierarchy is the catchall type Any. If there is no matching function at any level of the hierarchy, then the function call fails.

This is best illustrated by a simple example. We'll create a function f that responds to several different types in the type hierarchy with the name of the type:

```
julia> f(x::Int)="Int"
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x::Real)="Real"
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(x::Number)="Number"
f (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> f(x::Any)="Any"
f (generic function with 4 methods)

julia> f(x::Array)="Array"
f (generic function with 5 methods)

julia> f(4) # typeof(4) isInt64
"Int"

julia> f(2.0) # typeof(2.0) is Float64
"Real"

julia> f(3im) # typeof(3im) is Complex{Int64}

"Number"

julia> f([1,2]) # typeof([1,2]) is Array{Int64, 1}
"Array"

julia> f(Dict(1=>3,4=>5)) # typeof(Dict(1=>3,4=>5)) is Dict{Int64, Int64}
"Any"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer – that all makes sense. Is there some way that I can have my implementation (that'll work on indexable things with length) be less general? ie., have it more specific such that it attaches further away from the type root than the `Any` handler? I suppose I'd be wanting to define some "protocol" that matches "anything with length that's indexable", and define my function on that. The dispatch mechanism would then hook that on wherever applicable.