# How can I add a method to an existing function in Julia?

Tags: methods, julia

So within Julia, every function has methods.

The following makes sense:

```
f(x, y) = x + y
f(x) = x + 2
```

This provides two methods attached to this function.

But let's say I want to add a method to an existing Julia function, instead of overriding it.

For example:

```
a = [2, 3]
push!(a, 4)
a == [2, 3, 4] # true

type Node
   children :: Array{Node}
end

function push!(base :: Node, child :: Node)
   push!(base.children, child)
end
```

This is what I want to do; extend existing functions to act appropriately with new types. But this throws an error. Is this possible?

Comment: This is almost an [exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188800/can-i-write-i-julia-method-that-works-whenever-possible-like-a-c-template-fu/28204432#28204432). I'm not going to vote to close though as I actually think your question is much clearer than the linked question (although the answer(s) at the linked question are much more thorough).

Comment: Thanks—I didn't see that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just solved it, so I thought to still post the question, in case people have trouble in the future.

You have to explicitly import a function in order to extend it.

So this would work:

```
import Base.push!

function push!(base :: Node, child :: Node)
   push!(base.children, child)
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can spell this `function Base.push!(…`.  I personally like this style a bit better since you can tell at the function definition site if you're extending the Base method or not.  Otherwise, you need to scan through your whole file for the import statement.