# 'Foo' has no method matching Foo(::Bar)

Tags: julia

I'd like to start that I've not been able to recreate my problem in a stripped down version of the code. The code below works as intended, so this post is perhaps not well posed. The extended code, which is too long to post here, fails. I'll describe what I'm trying to do as maybe it'll help someone else out there.

I create three types: Bar, Baz, and Qux, which contains the method foo on Bar and Baz. I create a qux and query it's foo

```
qux = Wubble.Qux()
qux.foo
```

I get the following two methods, as expected:

```
foo(bar::Bar)
foo(baz::Baz)
```

Then when I try to actually use qux.foo with a bar or a baz, it gives me an error `'foo' has no method matching foo(::Bar)`.

Sadly, I can't recreate this error with stripped down code and the real code is unattractively long. What are the various ways of getting this error in this scenario that I've missed? It may be related to method extension and function shadowing like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948941/function-signature-not-found-despite-showing-with-methods), but I couldn't work a fix.

```
module Wibble
type Bar
  data::Number
  function Bar(num::Number=0)
    this = new(num)
    return this
  end
end
end

module Wobble
type Baz
  data::String
  function Baz(vec::String="a")
    this = new(vec)
    return this
  end
end
end

module Wubble
using Wibble
using Wobble
typealias Bar Wibble.Bar
typealias Baz Wobble.Baz

type Qux
  foo::Function
  function Methods(this::Qux)
    function foo(bar::Bar)
      println("foo with bar says ", bar.data)
    end
    function foo(baz::Baz)
      println("foo with baz says ", baz.data)
    end
    this.foo = foo
    return this
  end
  function Qux()
    this = new()
    this = Methods(this)
    return this
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's going wrong, but a couple of points which might help

- You almost never want to have `Function` field in a type: this is a common idiomatic mistake made by people coming from "dot-based" OOP languages. Julia methods are generic, and don't belong to a particular type. There is no advantage to doing this, and not only is it more confusing (you have a lot of nested levels to write something that could be written in 2 lines), but it can make it harder for the compiler to reason about types, impacting performance.
- You should use `import Wibble.Bar` instead of a `typealias`. If you use this, you don't need `using`.
- Outer constructors are easier to use for specifying default arguments.

So in short, my version would be:

```
module Wibble
type Bar
  data::Number
end
Bar() = Bar(0)
end

module Wobble
type Baz
  data::String
end
Baz() = Baz("a")
end

module Wubble
import Wibble.Bar
import Wobble.Baz

qux(bar::Bar) = println("foo with bar says ", bar.data)
qux(baz::Baz) = println("foo with baz says ", baz.data)

end
```

Comment: Good to know, but c++ explicit yet verbose encapsulation will be hard to unlearn.